# How to loop a sound file in MASM32

Tags: winapi, audio, assembly, masm, masm32

I am building a game in assembly, and I use `PlaySound()` to play a sound file in my game.

The `PlaySound()`function plays the sound file until the sound file ends (until it reaches the full sound file length). Is there a way to loop the function so it will not stop after it reaches the end of the file?

I am using  Windows 8 API, and writing in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have a closer look at the docs for `PlaySound`. There's a flag that you may be interested in. :)

Comment: At the last question it was suggested that you read the documentation. It is way more efficient for you to read the documentation. Your current plan seems to be to ask us here to read the documentation for you.

Comment: i did read :) wasnt noticing it .you dont have to be that rude though

Comment: I'm not being rude. You are the one being exceedingly rude by not reading the documentation. If you really did read it, then you cannot have failed to see `SND_LOOP` which could not be more obvious. Please do listen to the multiple requests for you to read docs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at the [API documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for `PlaySound`, you can see there are quite a number of flags for `fdwSound`. The flags you're looking for are `SND_LOOP` and `SND_ASYNC`:

Something like this (Please excuse any errors. My masm is a bit rusty):

```
mov eax, SND_FILENAME  ;; pszSound is a file name
or eax, SND_LOOP       ;; Play in a loop
or eax, SND_ASYNC      ;; Play in the background
invoke PlaySound, addr sound_file, 0, eax
```

Comment: i found something problematic. my playsound function  is in the MAIN area. and if i put the SND_LOOP there its make my game to crush..

Comment: @user4825345: Again, read the documentation (this is the THIRD time you have been told to do that): "*SND_LOOP The sound plays repeatedly until PlaySound is called again with the pszSound parameter set to NULL. **If this flag is set, you must also set the SND_ASYNC flag**.*" i updated Levi's example.